# Tags not saving or showing, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and without any luck been trying to figure this out for awhile now. For some reason i cannot get my tags to show up or save inside of the database.I really need some help, i looked online and the documentation is intermediate or not newbie friendly. Here is my code:

Devise User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

Products Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :date, :price, :tag_list

    acts_as_taggable_on :tags

    belongs_to :user
end
```

Form:

```
  <div class="field"> 
    <%= f.label :tag_list %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </div>
```

Show View:

```
<p>
    <b>Tags:</b> 
    <%= @product.tag_list %>     
</p>
```

**EDIT WITH UPDATED AND WORKING CODE:**

I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and letting only the [current_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397352/mymodel-user-current-user-is-not-working-for-me/6397380#6397380) (user_id in products table) do actions such as create,destroy,update tags,etc.

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products,        :dependent => :destroy
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

**Product Model:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :date, :price, :tag_list, :longitude, :latitude

    acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

**Products Controller:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end

  def new
   @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])

    @product.user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    @product.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

**products/index.html.erb:**

```
<td><%= product.tag_list %></td>
```

**products/show.html.erb:**

```
<p>
    <b>Tags:</b> 
    <%= @product.tag_list %>     
</p>
```

Comment: Whats the ERB look like for that form and what does the controller look like for the Product?

Comment: I updated it to show you my Products Controller.

Comment: Are lines like this `#@product = Product.new(params[:product])` commented out in your app? That means that nothing gets saved. You need to fix your devise/cancan roles if that is the reason you commented them out.

Comment: @Devin M Yeah it seems to be a problem with my roles so i uncommented them and they started working but now i have to figure out my Devise set up becuase CanCan is all screwed up. I am trying to get it so the Current User only can do all of  the above actions. Anyways, thanks for the help Devin!

Comment: Post another question about cancan if you want and I should be able to help. Just give me a link here when its up.

Comment: @Devin M I got rid of CanCan just in-case i have conflicts with future code because i don't understand Ruby or Rails enough yet and don't want to be "gem-dependent". I defintely will be asking questions in the future that deal with acts-as-taggable-on though, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code in your view:

```
<p>
    <b>Tags:</b> 
    <%= @product.tags %>     
</p>
```

Comment: I will give you credit for this because it lead me to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar. I hadn't added :tag_list to my events_controller (I'm making a bare-bones meetup clone for my youth group) -

```
private
        def event_params
            params.require(:event).permit(:title, :text, :user_id, :event_start, :time_begin, :location, :address, **:tag_list**)
        end
end
```

Wasn't throwing any other errors than that, luckily I thought of this too.